# NTLM with Postman shows "JSONError | Unexpected token '<' at 1:1 "

Tags: postman, ntlm, postman-collection-runner, ntlm-authentication

I have script to do API automation by fetching data from CSV file and comparing JSON response with the data in CSV file in POSTMAN. I have 12 scenarios/ iterations  to verify and each scenario sends more than 20 data picking from CSV file and from JSON response compared more than 10 data. Everything is working fine.

Now Security feature implemented in code, so I have to send the request and Automate the script with ID/PWD. So I used NTML authentication with ID and PWD.

When I run the script with runner, initial two iteration gives perfect response and script passed, then from 3rd iteration all script failed and not getting response. In response it says Data unavailable when I checked in postman console it shows below details.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What could be the reason and any solution to solve this.

[Screen short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVe5j.png)

Used NTLM Authentication [BETA] authorization option with ID/PWD

Here are the details for pass scenario

```
Request Headers:
content-type:"application/json"
cache-control:"no-cache"
user-agent:"PostmanRuntime/7.1.5"
accept:"*/*"
host:"xxxxxx"
accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate"
content-length:599
authorization:"NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAFIAAAAYABgAagAAAAAAAABIAAAACgAKAEgAAAAAAAAAUgAAAAAAAACCAAAABYKIogUBKAoAAAAPUAAzAFcATABJAPxv7ESeMEwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHZECYztsK+qnjG5K0DvDIPzQ09CFXWo0Q=="

Request Body:

Response Headers:
transfer-encoding:"chunked"
content-type:"application/json; charset=utf-8"
location:"xxxxxx/api/rate/zzz"
server:"Kestrel"
persistent-auth:"true"
date:"Wed, 06 Jun 2018 13:40:05 GMT"

Response Body:
rate:5
retailRateAttributes:
error:null
```

Here are the details of Failed scenario

```
   Request Headers:
content-type:"application/json"
cache-control:"no-cache"
authorization:"NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAFIAAAAYABgAagAAAAAAAABIAAAACgAKAEgAAAAAAAAAUgAAAAAAAACCAAAABYKIogUBKAoAAAAPUAAzAFcATABJAPxv7ESeMEwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHZECYztsK+qnjG5K0DvDIPzQ09CFXWo0Q=="
user-agent:"PostmanRuntime/7.1.5"
accept:"*/*"
host:""xxxxxx""
accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate"
content-length:599

Request Body:

Response Headers:
content-type:"text/html"
server:"Microsoft-IIS/10.0"
www-authenticate:
0:"Negotiate"
1:"NTLM"
date:"Wed, 06 Jun 2018 13:40:05 GMT"
content-length:"1293"

Response Body:
```

Answer (score 2):

While Postman errors are not the most descriptive, this error typically occurs because your API endpoint does not exist. You may want to check that you are correctly calling the appropriate endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You say that the two first iterations work fine but when you get to the third iteration, get the error. That sounds like the auth/token/session expired.

Comment: Thanks Ove, butI am confused on auth/token/session expired. 1)  I have given id/pwd, if my understanding correct, each call should happen with ID/PWD and generates new token. 2) Is there any way, I can solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tested to see if each call actually DOES generate a new token?

Comment: Yes I checked, each call generate token and all most all token are different hash format. Another thing I observed is, two token are same but one gives correct response and another is failed. <I compared the tokens pasting in notepad and looks equal>

Comment: You need to make sure that a new token is generated correctly, depending on what requirements you have for when you test. I had a similar problem myself a while ago where it did not update the variable for the token correctly.

Comment: I had a discussion with dev folks, as per their design only id/pwd required to consume the API. can you please help me how to generate the token correctly with screenshots ? this might help me to solve this issue. you can send details @lalit.sah@gmail.com too.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Postman error message
`JSONError: Unexpected token '<' at 1:1<!doctype html>^` today.
I realized that the problem (in my case) was that I tried to access an API that
I had written myself, but forgotten to upload. - Thus, I tried to call an API
that did not exist. (!)

As soon as I uploaded the API, the error went away.

Comment: Confirmed again today - the Postman error message `JSONError: Unexpected token '<' at 1:1<!doctype html>^` is typical when requesting an API that does not exist (because of wrong spelling or whatever).

Comment: Closely related is the error message `JSONError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` which is typical [when you try to GET a Postman variable that doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67776344).