# Postman error when running tests: JSONError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, request, postman, spotify

Steps to reproduce error: https://blog.getpostman.com/2016/11/09/generate-spotify-playlists-using-a-postman-collection/

I have been following the above tutorial for sending an API request to Spotify. I am successful in getting the authorisation codes, however, Postman has an error when running the collection for Spotify despite following the tutorial correctly. 
[image: 2 Successful, 2 failed]

From looking at the console, there is an error at the line shown below:
[image: error at line shown]
**Error message reads**
XPath runner/search already exists
**Error running scripts: JSONError | Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
Error executing pre-request scripts for Get Artist Top Tracks: JSONError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0**
[image: see bottom right corner]
Two others experienced the issue but they were never replied to. Any ideas how to fix this? I am new to API requests so any help would be muchly appreciated!
[image: Two others experience the issue, unanswered question]

Pre request script for auth:

```
var client_credentials = (environment.client_id + ':' + environment.client_secret).encodeBase64();
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("client_credentials", client_credentials);

environment.cloned_environment && (delete environment.cloned_environment);
var environmentObjClone = _.cloneDeep(environment);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("cloned_environment", JSON.stringify(environmentObjClone));
```

Pre-Request Script for artist:

```
 try {
    var artist_id = _.sample(JSON.parse(environment.artists));
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("id", artist_id);
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    throw false;
}
```

JSON:

```
  {
        "id": "b2b45667-7ec9-4d5d-9e38-c976d181c2bd",
        "name": "SpotifyGenV1.template1",
        "values": [
            {
                "key": "artists",
                "value": "[“2DaxqgrOhkeH0fpeiQq2f4”, “2ooIqOf4X2uz4mMptXCtie”]",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": "N",
                "value": "5",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": "user_id",
                "value": "marcz2007",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": "country_code",
                "value": "US",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": "client_id",
                "value": "744a1316f9374a27b7ec9bc7eabb0f92",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": "client_secret",
                "value": "---secret--",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": "refresh_token",
                "value": "AQAf0rvuNBo23wiIiyWQRfavFvx7JdTjvGYLufOBAM1ABtvXWvfqqo_I0IfhFAelTPIh8w2cscS4C1k8QLKOc1rqn18CjKJbmczfu1X-EfEFaWjcDbIPYGCIGZmbNZv5DgiJ9w",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": "client_credentials",
                "value": "NzQ0YTEzMTZmOTM3NGEyN2I3ZWM5YmM3ZWFiYjBmOTI6M2ZiNWM2MDBkODRhNDU1ODhmZTNiZWM4MTI5N2E4M2Y=",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": "cloned_environment",
                "value": "{\"artists\":\"[“2DaxqgrOhkeH0fpeiQq2f4”, “2ooIqOf4X2uz4mMptXCtie”]\",\"N\":\"5\",\"user_id\":\"marcz2007\",\"country_code\":\"US\",\"client_id\":\"744a1316f9374a27b7ec9bc7eabb0f92\",\"client_secret\":\"3fb5c600d84a45588fe3bec81297a83f\",\"refresh_token\":\"AQAf0rvuNBo23wiIiyWQRfavFvx7JdTjvGYLufOBAM1ABtvXWvfqqo_I0IfhFAelTPIh8w2cscS4C1k8QLKOc1rqn18CjKJbmczfu1X-EfEFaWjcDbIPYGCIGZmbNZv5DgiJ9w\",\"client_credentials\":\"NzQ0YTEzMTZmOTM3NGEyN2I3ZWM5YmM3ZWFiYjBmOTI6M2ZiNWM2MDBkODRhNDU1ODhmZTNiZWM4MTI5N2E4M2Y=\",\"authorization\":\"BQD6I914g3iIt3zs1lpZl7nriwNgkFNMuIjIPjEa6ElTZw_PEbx3ewZkb38zlhypR5BfuyXLUxdJ0WyZ1TWETMSPYpPwBk7Olf6E5J49Q67BhgFWp5A4HyxYHgXNO-56sbOGx1aszETJ24Q8uGfOizzsv9WhpVU2cuC8lJdA3K2aYqc0L-8JnmD0VIrQhwX0\",\"playlist_id\":\"0cfptAtDW6jHMeWauwQ13w\",\"artist_name\":\"Oasis\",\"artistID\":\"2DaxqgrOhkeH0fpeiQq2f4\",\"trackID\":\"4AKUOaCRcoKTFnVI9LtsrN\"}",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": "authorization",
                "value": "BQD6I914g3iIt3zs1lpZl7nriwNgkFNMuIjIPjEa6ElTZw_PEbx3ewZkb38zlhypR5BfuyXLUxdJ0WyZ1TWETMSPYpPwBk7Olf6E5J49Q67BhgFWp5A4HyxYHgXNO-56sbOGx1aszETJ24Q8uGfOizzsv9WhpVU2cuC8lJdA3K2aYqc0L-8JnmD0VIrQhwX0",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": "playlist_id",
                "value": "0cfptAtDW6jHMeWauwQ13w",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": "artist_name",
                "value": "Oasis",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": "artist_id",
                "value": "2DaxqgrOhkeH0fpeiQq2f4",
                "enabled": true
            },

        ],
        "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
        "_postman_exported_at": "2019-07-28T12:45:10.195Z",
        "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/7.3.4"
    }
```

Comment: As you're getting a 400 error is probably something wrong in your code. Can you share an image of what you have in your pre-request script for those requests. The blog was from 3 years ago so there is also a possibility that Spotify has also change since then. I would suspect from that error it's to do with parsing the request body.

Comment: Yes that could be it, I've editted in the pre request scripts above (which was empty for the https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{{id}}/related-artists one). Anything catch your eye as being wrong here?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and what's really weird is that this same call used to work.  I even did a demo on it and havent' changed the code since.  And yes, I am set to the same environment as before.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't read your question in detail, but
`JSONError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` is *the* typical
error message when you try to *GET* a Postman variable that doesn't
exist.
(Because of misspelling or whatever.)

Closely related is the error message
`JSONError: Unexpected token '<' at 1:1<!doctype html>^` which
[typically occurs when you try to request a *URL* that doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65642938).

Answer (score 0):

A missing environment variable is one cause. Also ensure that the value is present in the `Initial Value` section and not just the `Current Value`

**Another is accidently leaving a return character in a variable which will give the following**

`unexpected token \n in JSON...`

Remove the return character (postman UI shows it as the return symbol and not the character itself) and it resolves this issue.